# How to invalidate a user token in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

so, I'm a user manager and I want to delete an account which also means I want to invalidate that particular user access token.

I have inbuilt loopback accesstoken table which has token and userId.

```
Person.find({ where: { id: userId } }).then(user, function(){
   user.logout(user.id);
});
```

when I do this, I get the follwing error
Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

I'm not sure how to logout other users.

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete all the access tokens associated to that user from AccessToken table.

Below is the sample code for your reference :

```
            User.app.models.AccessToken.destroyAll({
                userId
            }, (err) => {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                return callback(null,true);
            });
```

Comment: Great answer! I would just correct that this is : ```.destroyAll({
                userId: user.id
            }, ...)```